# CASE with max()

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin, greatest-n-per-group

I know how to do this in SQL Server but Postgres is different.
I want to return the max employee pay.

```
Select b.enumber, b.bday, 
case when Max(c.id) then c.pay
ELSE c.pay
End As "Current Pay"
From employee b
inner join humanr c
on b.empid = c.empid
```

This produces an error:

> ERROR:  argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type integer

How can I return the pay from `max(id)`?

The `humanr` table datastructure is `id`, `employeeid`, `date`, and `pay`. This table will contain the hourly pay for every employee based on `employeeid`. For each employee in the `employee` table, I am wanting to return the pay from `MAX(id)` so that the current pay is returned for the employee.

Example:

```
1  1234  01/01/2016  8.00
2  1234  04/04/2016  10.00
3  5555  05/01/2016  12.00
4  1234  05/16/2016  10.50
```

So for *5555* I would want *12.00* returned, and for *1234* I would want *10.50*.

Comment: Your expression needs an equivalency.  WHEN MAX(c.ID) ???.  what are you comparing max(c.id) to?  For example, this would work.  CASE WHEN MAX(c.id) > 1 THEN XXX.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ & Jonathan Fite --- see edit for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Many will work both in SQL Server and Postgres, like using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
WITH cte AS
( SELECT e.enumber, e.bday, c.empid, c.pay,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.empid 
                            ORDER BY c.id DESC)
           AS rn
  FROM employee AS e
    INNER JOIN humanr AS c
      ON e.empid = c.empid
) 
SELECT enumber, bday, empid, pay AS current_pay
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 ;
```

By the way, if you want the latest pay, why is the `ORDER BY id DESC` should be used and not the `ORDER BY c.date DESC`? It would make more sense.

---

Another, proprietary Postgres way to do this is using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.empid)
    e.enumber, e.bday, c.empid
    c.pay AS current_pay
FROM employee AS e
  INNER JOIN humanr AS c
    ON e.empid = c.empid
ORDER BY c.empid, c.id DESC ;
```

---

And another, usually more efficient way that needs a recent version (9.3+) is using the `LATERAL` syntax (similar to `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` in SQL Server):

```
SELECT e.enumber, e.bday, e.empid
       c.pay AS current_pay
FROM employee AS e
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
    ( SELECT ci.*
      FROM humanr AS ci
      WHERE e.empid = ci.empid
      ORDER BY ci.id DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS c ;
```

Which technique is *more efficient* depends on data distribution. See [this benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134).

Answer (score 0):

You should get the maximum value from c.pay then:

```
Select b.enumber, b.bday, 
max(c.pay) as current_pay
From employee b
inner join humanr c
on b.empid = c.empid
group by b.enumber, b.bday
```